# Wifi keeps dropping when downloading

Tags: windows-10, wifi-driver

Not sure where I have to put this but it's annoying the hell out of me. Whenever I try to download a file form the internet or from P2P network my wifi connection just drops and won't reconnect again until I reboot my laptop.

I've tried multiple things but so far came up zilth.

What I have tried

- Updating WiFi driver
- Disallow power management to shut down adaptor
- Checked the bandwith connection from the internet. Fast enough and it isn't saturating the connection
- winsock reset
- tried booting in safe mode - > no result

I'm running out idea's.. Anyone else have an idea ?

Network Adapaters 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the router? Does it also drop with a wired connection?

Comment: Yup tried that aswell, even did a factory reset on the router

Comment: And a wired connection?

Comment: No, not with the wired connection, it's only with WiFi

Comment: Try reinstalling the (latest) Wifi Adapter drivers ....

Comment: While downloading the driver it happen again btw

Comment: So download the driver on a wired connection .... I though that would be obvious ....

Comment: Your problem is fixed?

Comment: Correct @DavidPostill thanks for the obvious answer. Sometimes u need a new set of eyes to see the obvious. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidPostill suggested I reinstalled my WiFi drivers and it is stable again.